# webpack Resolve conflict? Should I use alias?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to configure webpack to use clean import in my react app:

```
import { userConstants } from 'constants';
```

instead of:

```
import { userConstants } from '../../constants';
```

In webpack.config.js I defined:

```
resolve: {
  modules: [
    "node_modules",
    helpers.root('client/app')
  ],
  extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
},
```

This worked very well until I added a folder called `constants`. I wonder if some kind of conflict might appear with my `node_modules` since I get an error that disappears when I change the folder name to `_constants`:

> WARNING in ./client/app/actions/user.actions.js 83:12-25 "export
>   'userConstants' was not found in 'constants'

**My question:** Should I define an alias in the webpack config for each of my folders? `components`, `containers`, `constants`, `reducers`, `actions`, `services`?

Comment: do you have a `constants/index.js` file?

Comment: yes with `export * from './alert.constants'; export * from './user.constants';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you have to use alias for each of your folder like this:

```
alias: {
    constants: path.resolve(APP_DIR, 'constants'),
    api: path.resolve(APP_DIR, 'api'),
    components: path.resolve(APP_DIR, 'components'),
    reducers: path.resolve(APP_DIR, 'reducers'),
  }
```

This would be helpful in resolving and importing modules. And make sure you have correct `APP_DIR`